# VBA .getElementbyID and passing value to an onchange javascript event

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript

I have the following code which selects an item from the drop down by using the .getelementbyid method.  The way the page works is once the item is selected, a new screen populates allowing to send a user a message to someone (the form uses an onchange event to handle when you select an item from the drop down list).  When running this code, it selects the proper item but the page does not repopulate.

```
With HTMLDoc2

.getElementById("navbar1").setAttribute "value", "getaddr"

End With
```

How do you force the form to recognize that you have selected one of the drop down items and process the onchange event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for a similar answer and found this that may be useful.

I have a SELECT element on a web page (which has an ID) that has an onchange javascript associated with it.
I accessed it as follows (using your example):-

```
dim objURLpage as MSHTML.HTMLdocument

dim appIE as InternetExplorer

dim objSELECTelement as MSHTML.HTMLSelectElement
```

'this type will depend on your HTML element type but usually dropdown lists are "OPTION" elements between "SELECT" elements

```
Set objURLpage = appIE.document  'I found this gives current web page that's open

set objSELECTelement = objURLpage.getElemebtById("navbar1")

objSELECTelement.selectedindex = 0
```

'number depends on position of item in dropdown list starting at "0"

```
objSELECTelement.FireEvent("onchange")
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot I still had this question open!  I ended up figuring it out, but im sure this will help someone else.

Comment: Thank you ! Works perfectly